# How to call specific column value object and store to another psobject?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make another table from different data coming from an storage object.

`$resultHOlder = @()` <--------- These are datasets stored in an object

`$ObjectTypesData = @()` <--------- These are datasets stored in an object

```
function Get-Data {
                $table= new-object psobject
                $table| Add-Member  ADLocalAdmin $resultHOlder.'Object_Name'
                $table| Add-Member ObjecTypes  $ObjectTypesData.'ObjectClass'
                return $table
        }
            Get-Data
```

I am getting a result Like this

```
ADLocalAdmin                                  ObjecTypes
------------                                  ----------
{$admin1, $admin2, $admin3…}                {group, group, group…}
```

Output that I am trying to achieve:

```
 ADLocalAdmin                                  ObjecTypes
    ------------                                  ----------
    Admin1                                        group
    Admin2                                        group
    Admin3                                        group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "zip" two arrays together, use a `for` loop:

```
function Get-Data {
  param(
    [array]$ADLocalAdminValues,
    [array]$ObjecTypeValues
  )

  if($ADLocalAdminValues.Length -ne $ObjectTypeValues.Length){
    Write-Error "Expected input arrays to be of the same size"
    return
  }

  for($i = 0; $i -lt $ADLocalAdminValues.Length; $i++){
    # Create and output new object with the values found at index $i in each array
    [pscustomobject]@{
      ADLocalAdmin = $ADLocalAdminValues[$i].Object_name
      ObjectType = $ObjectTypeValues[$i].ObjectClass
    }
  }
}
```

Then invoke it like:

```
$result = Get-Data -ADLocalAdminValues $resultHOlder -ObjectTypeValues $ObjectTypesData
```

Comment: I tried one array param just to call atleast 1 with these code 

function Get-Data {
    param(
      [array]$ADLocalAdminValues
    )
  
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $ADLocalAdminValues.Length; $i++){
      # Create and output new object with the values found at index $i in each array
      [pscustomobject]@{
        ADLocalAdmin = $ADLocalAdminValues[$i].Object_Name
      }
    }
  }

Get-Data -$ADLocalAdminValues $resultHOlder

Comment: Theres no value output

Comment: @Den10102020 You need to pass both arrays: `Get-Data -ADLocalAdminValues $resultHOlder -ObjectTypeValues $ObjectTypesData`

Comment: FWIW No output means both arrays are empty